# How to save a dictionary of [String:[Object]] to Firebase in swift

Tags: swift, object, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

What is the best way to save a dictionary from type [String:[object]] to firebase ?

The object class is :

```
class Product {

let name:String
var cost:Double
let image:UIImage
var quantity:Int

init(name:String,cost:Double,imageName:String)
{
    self.name=name
    self.cost=cost
    self.image = UIImage(named: imageName)!
    self.quantity = 0
}
init()
{
    self.name=""
    self.cost=0
    self.image = UIImage()
    self.quantity=0
}
```

}

Thanks